# Preg_match for alternative values in regex php not work

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need help. I don't understand why it not works.
I have following html. (Frau = Mrs, Herr=Mr.)

```
Herr John Doe <br />
<br />
Frau Jane Smith <br />
```

I have following regex in my php-code with preg_match.

```
preg_match_all("!<li class='default highlightProfilePremium'>(.*?)<\/li>!is", $result, $match);

for ($i=0;$i<count($match[1]);$i++){
    if(preg_match("!Herr(.*\W)<br \/>|Frau(.*\W)<br \/>!",$match[1][$i], $contact)) {
        $list['contact'][$i] = $contact[1];
    } else {
        $list['contact'][$i] = '';
    };
}
```

In regex101 both of this regex were found. In php, however, he only ever finds one.
What am I doing wrong.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I think you are looking for `preg_match_all`

Comment: I edit my post. I use the preg_match_all function. And I saw the other post. preg_match except only one match. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: You don't have to duplicate the entire expression just to alternate a single word. `!(?:Herr|Frau)(.*\W)<br \/>!`. For reference, `(?:)` is a non-capturing group. https://www.debuggex.com/r/pcBLxIUdsNVbPv0O